# Get an error as I try continuously re tweet. What gap should I impose before I reach the limit of 1000?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

In the section *[Current Twitter Limits](http://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-twitter-limits-api-updates-and-following)* , there is a mention :

```
Tweets: 1,000 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into
smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as Tweets.
```

I understand the daily limit of 1,000 per day but what is *..smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals.* What is that limit ?

I am writing an application whose one module will retweet based on a certain `hashtag`. If the hash tag is `#Ghazal`, it shall keep re tweeting till the limit of 1000 is reached. But I am unable to do so. When I run application, it re tweeted 11 tweets when I got this error :

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
{"errors":"sharing is not permissible for this status (Share validations failed)"}

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b029ad3d or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=132d0e3b
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b029ad3d-132d0e3b], statusCode=403, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.6-SNAPSHOT(build: afd755d42f0c2fd7a2a87cedf1e91e123de2d754)}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:2023)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.retweetStatus(TwitterImpl.java:283)
    at org.tester.TweetSearcher.processRequest(TweetSearcher.java:73)
    at org.tester.TweetSearcher.doGet(TweetSearcher.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What gap should I impose, so that I do not get this error ?

Comment: The exception message "sharing is not permissible for this status" suggests another kind of problem. Maybe the tweet was deleted? 11 tweets/half-hour sounds like very small a limit (since 1000/24/2 ≈ 21).

Comment: @RandomSeed So update of 21 is permissible in 0.5 hour ?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, I just deduced the limit must be >20 or else there is no way to reach 1000/day.